# Semantic-UI's search element returns a TypeError

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

I'm attempting to get Semantic UI's search [Using Different Response Fields](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html#/examples) feature working.

When I attempt to use the search, I get this:

[image]

rather than this:

[image]

The page's header contains:

```
<!-- Semantic UI-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">

<!-- font awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-/rXc/GQVaYpyDdyxK+ecHPVYJSN9bmVFBvjA/9eOB+pb3F2w2N6fc5qB9Ew5yIns" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Semantic UI-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

I've defined the search in the page's body, including the document-ready script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log('ready');
  console.debug('steady');

  $('.ui.search')
    .search({
      apiSettings: {
        url: '//api.github.com/search/repositories?q={query}'
      },
      fields: {
        results : 'items',
        title   : 'name',
        url     : 'html_url'
      },
      minCharacters : 3
    });

});
</script>
<div class="ui search">
  <div class="ui left icon input">
    <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Search GitHub">
    <i class="github icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the browser's console I get an error:

> TypeError: P.ajax is not a function[Learn More]

[image]

** edit **

I went through the effort of installing and building Semantic UI, following the [instructions](https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html).

I moved the contents of the `dist` folder to my application's `public` folder, which now resemble:

[image]

I modified the page's reference to include the desired components:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="components/search.min.css">
<script src="semantic.min.js"></script>
<script src="components/search.min.js"></script>
```

Now I get a different TypeError:

[image]

** / edit **

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the slim version of jQuery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

When I switched to using the regular version:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The search worked as expected.